# Absolute and relative path imports on React and Visual studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, create-react-app

I've created a React app using create-react-app in VisualStudio. I'm trying to avoid having to use a bunch of `../../` in order to import my different components. Supposedly I should be able to use either the `jsconfig.json` file or `.env` files to setup `baseUrl` or `NODE_URL`. However, I'm clearly doing something wrong because I can't access my files. My file structure looks something like this:

```
+ClientApp
  package.json
  +public
  +src
    +buttons
      Button.js
    +components
      +sidebar
        Sidebar.js
        SidebarButton.js
gulpfile.js
package.json
Program.cs
Startup.cs
```

What I want to do is to import the button component inside `Button.js` in my `SidebarButton.js` file using something like `src/buttons/Button.js` or a similar path. However, I can't get the environment to start its lookup for files from the `src` directory. An absolute path will start the lookup from my C:\ directory and any relative lookup will start from the current directory of the js file doing the import

Comment: Here is the [usefull answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265583/how-would-one-write-a-resolve-alias-function-for-gulp) for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Imports

You can configure your application to support importing modules using absolute paths. This can be done by configuring a jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json file in the root of your project. If you're using TypeScript in your project, you will already have a tsconfig.json file.

Below is an example jsconfig.json file for a JavaScript project. You can create the file if it doesn't already exist:

> {   "compilerOptions": {
> "baseUrl": "src"   },   "include": ["src"] }

If you're using TypeScript, you can configure the baseUrl setting inside the compilerOptions of your project's tsconfig.json file.

Now that you've configured your project to support absolute imports, if you want to import your module located at src/buttons/Button.js, you can import the module like so:

> import Button from 'buttons/Button';

For more information on these configuration files, see the [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) reference and [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) reference documentation.